# Google Map is not loading when I use proguard

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application project.properties I have added `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` to use proguard.
And I have imported the apk file like --> export -->export android application -->create new keystore so on....

And created apk file, when I run this apk in my device google map is not loading,
How to solve the issue?

Comment: Is it possible you might've forgotten to add an API key for Google Maps that is built against your 'live' key - the key with which you signed your apk when creating the release build?. If you only have a single key, that worked while debugging, it's probably signed against Eclipse's debug key. Read more about this [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html).

Comment: i have created only 1 key to display map and added in my xml, so i need to create the key again? i am little confused..

Comment: It's al explained in the link I pointed our earlier, more specifically, read ['Getting the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate'](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint) vs ['Getting the MD5 Fingerprint of Your Signing Certificate'](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getfingerprint).

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, while exporting the apk i need to point to the keysore that i have used for displaying maps, it is working now thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you might've forgotten to add an API key for Google Maps that is built against your 'live' key - the key with which you signed your apk when creating the release build?. If you only have a single key, that worked while debugging, it's probably signed against Eclipse's debug key. Read more about this [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_your_apps_certificate_information).

It's al explained in the link I pointed our earlier, more specifically, read ['Displaying the **debug** certificate fingerprint'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_the-debug_certificate_fingerprint) vs ['Displaying the **release** certificate fingerprint'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_the-release_certificate_fingerprint).

Comment: These links are all broken.

Comment: @rrbrambley: Correct, because the question originally concerned Android Google Maps API v1. I've updated the links to the relevant sections in the v2 API documentation.